# Dynamic formatting

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I can use `"%.5f" % var_name` to format a float `var_name` where `5` represents a fixed number of decimal places. How can I dynamically change this number? I tried `"%.%f" % var_name, 5` and `"#{var_name}.#{5}f"`, but they didn't work.

Comment: You are confusing `"#{}"` and `String#%`. The former is part of the string literal syntax. The latter is an operation that applies to a string already created. You can't mix them; they apply at different timing.

Comment: The name for what @Uri suggests is ["string interpolation"](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics).  Note that it does not work when the string is defined with single quotes (e.g., `num = 4; "%.#{num}f" % 0.001 #=> "0.0010"`; `'%.#{num}f' % 0.001 #=> ArgumentError: flag after precision`).  That is the main distinction between the use of single and double quotes.

Comment: @sawa I don't follow. What do you mean by "apply at different timing"?

Comment: `"#{}` is applied at the time of string creation. `%` is applied after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try:

```
"%.#{5}f" % var_name
```

with variables:

```
var_name = 0.00001
num = 5

"%.#{num}f" % var_name
# => "0.00001"

num = 6
"%.#{num}f" % var_name
# => "0.000010"
```